# Selenium 2 Node on Azure VM ( Windows Server )

Tags: windows, azure, selenium

I have a selenium grid 2 Hub hosted in my Unix Server. To perform IEx tests, i've tried to attach a node on **Azure VM** (a Windows Server 2012 instance ) to my Selenium hub. The node appears on the Hub server interface ( ip:4444/console/grid )

But when i try to perform tests on it with a simple java code, a log error message appears saying : **Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connection timed out.**

For information i'm using the vIP of the VM ( the public one as they said ).

Could some one helps me since i'm a new azure user ?

Thank you :)